# Extracting between tokens with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm experimenting with NLTK to help me parse some text. So far , just using the sent_tokenize function has been very helpful in organizing the text. As an example I have:

```
1 Robins Drive owned by Gregg S. Smith was sold to TeStER, LLC of 494 Bridge Avenue, Suite 101-308, Sheltville AZ 02997 for $27,000.00.
```

using:

```
words =pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

I get:

```
[('1', 'CD'), ('Robins', 'NNP'), ('Drive', 'NNP'), ('owned', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('Gregg', 'NNP'), ('S.', 'NNP'), ('Smith', 'NNP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('sold', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('TeStER', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('LLC', 'NNP'), ('of', 'IN'), ('494', 'CD'), ('Bridge', 'NNP'), ('Avenue', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('Suite', 'NNP'), ('101-308', 'CD'), (',', ','), ('Sheltville', 'NNP'), ('AZ', 'NNP'), ('02997', 'CD'), ('for', 'IN'), ('$', '$'), ('27,000.00', 'CD'), ('.', '.')]
```

I have been looking at various tutorials and the book http://www.nltk.org/book/ , but I'm not sure of the best approach to extracting between 2 tokens. For example I want to select the tokens between "owned by" and "was sold to" to get the owner name. how can I best use NLTK functions and python to do this?

Comment: Wonder if there is a non-regex solution using, say, collocations or ngrams..

Comment: Take a look at `distance-supervision`: http://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/mintz.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This is one solution to select tokens between the words you wrote:

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'owned by(.*?)was sold to')

string = '1 Robins Drive owned by Gregg S. Smith was sold to TeStER, LLC of 494 Bridge Avenue, Suite 101-308, Sheltville AZ 02997 for $27,000.00.'
s = tokenizer.tokenize(string)
```

returns:

```
[' Gregg S. Smith ']
```

Comment: Thank you, although that is effective in this case I wondered about a solution taking advantage of the POS tagging as well.